# My `UIWebView` is supporting zooming on iPad but not for iPad mini

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

My `UIWebView` is supporting zooming on iPad but not for iPad mini I have used `setScalesPageToFit:YES`

Comment: Are they running the same version of iOS? I would be more inclined to think this is an iOS version issue than a device issue, since the devices should behave identically.

Comment: both ipad and ipad mini are having ios version 7.0.0 to 7.1.

Comment: You mean one of each, or you have multiple iPads and multiple iPad minis? Because it could have been a bug in 7.0 that they fixed in 7.1, or maybe it worked in 7.0 and was broken by 7.1.

Comment: ok.I have multiple devices though not of each version. zooming is not working for ipad mini only. is there any device setting that could affect zooming on webview?

Comment: No. But is there a correlation between the iOS version and the ability to zoom? That’s what I’m trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

To work properly, you should write `setScalesPageToFit:YES` after UIWebView is loaded completely.

That means you will write `setScalesPageToFit:YES` inside `webViewDidFinishLoad`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [yourWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
}
```

If above is not working, try below.

I remember I had faced such problem, which is weird. When I click sizeToFit in IB, all worked properly.

---

### Edit 1

Check below problem. Might be you have same problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19662549/1066828